# Custom Settings - Validation Rule

Tags: validation, customsetting

We have a custom setting (AllowableCombinations__c) that has the following fields

Queue,Type,Name,Area

It has 10 records containing the different allowable combinations of Queue/Type/Area and Sub Area.

We want to know whether it is possible to create a **validation rule** that can throw error if the record to be saved does not contain any of the combinations using the combinations from the custom setting.

*I know we can accomplish this via trigger or via hierarchial picklist.(.but that helps only when the record is created from UI ) but we really want to know whether it is possible to enforce this lookup validation via custom settings.*

Comment: If you'll build a composite key of these 4 values (a string similar to "somequeue-sometype-somename-somearea") you might be able to pull it off with VLOOKUP function. No idea if it works only on real custom objects or custom settings too. Check http://salesforcebyamit.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/vlookup-function.html for example?

Comment: I started an Idea some months back that you could vote on https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kwE8AAI; sad to say, it is not getting much traction

Comment: I don't believe triggers can be used for custom settings objects. Can someone correct me if I'm wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Only `Hierarchy` settings can be accessed using `$Setup` global in validation formula context.

Comment: Maybe if the Hierarchical custom setting had 4 fields x 10 combinations = 40 fields on it?